# Java - Scheduling a daily task

Tags: java, scheduling, timer, task

I'm looking for an effective way to execute a method everyday at 3PM regardless of when the application was initially run or how long it has been running.

This must be done entirely from the application with no OS intervention (ex. Windows Task Scheduler)

I have been experimenting with java.util.Timer in varies configurations but I have had no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of difficulty are you having? It should be straight forward to have a timer wake up periodically and check the time of day and look at your application 'cron' table to see if anything should be done. No?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should take a look at [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) which is a Java-based job scheduling system.

Comment: Definitely use Quartz. It is my favorite scheduler. Runs as a charm

Comment: I have always wondered. You need a running application to run Quartz in first place right? Is it possible to run it when no application has been started? How can a java  application run in the background? ( maybe running within a TrayIcon or something like that? )

Comment: Yes, there must be a Java application running that includes Quartz. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326509/java-background-daemon-service-cross-platform-best-pratices for running Java applications in the background.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to use something like the [quartz engine](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) it can do things like execute tasks that missed (like during a *ahem* crash) and it takes the work out of trying to manage threads.

For example if you use threads and put it to sleep and wake it up 86400 seconds (one day) later you will wake up and hour late (day = 82800 seconds) or early (day = 90000 seconds) on DST change over day, so be careful with whatever solution you choose

Answer (score 2):

A built-in JDK way is to do what others suggested and first calculate :

- currentTime - desiredTime

Then you can use something like [a schedule executor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to submit the tasks, and run them with a particular delay.  This is far simpler than the options you have with frameworks like  [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), but doesn't require an external dependency.

Also, you should always list which JDK you're using, so people can provide solutions for your version of the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a thread that calculates the difference to the next 3pm and sleeps for that time. When it wakes up it executes the method and recalculates and sleeps. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by others Quartz is a choice, with it you can do cron-like operations, jobs or triggers, here is a link on this subject: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-quartz/index.html

Answer (score 1):

[Jcrontab](http://www.jcrontab.org/index.shtml)

> Jcrontab is a scheduler written in Java. The project objective is to provide a fully functional schedules for Java projects.